# Doctrine migrations order

Tags: php, doctrine, database-migration, doctrine-migrations

Doctrine generates migrations with the `Version{YmdHis}` name formatting.

Imagine that several teams work on a project. And there are two branches in a VCS: `fix_tablename` and `feature_tablename`.

`feature_tablename` has a migration that adds a new field `foo_field`. And `fix_tablename` has a migration that changes `bar_field` to `foo_field`.

The migration in the first branch has an earlier version. At the next step, we merge both branches in the `release_august` branch. So we have a hardly detectable conflict. What's the better approach to use Doctrine migrations in big teams?

P.S. At the previous project we had our custom migration system. All the migrations had incremental (1, 2, 3) versions. And in the case described above, we had a VCS conflict because of the migration file names.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is doctrine problem. If I understood you correct, you have two branches, in the first branch you are creating `foo_field` and in the second you renaming `bar_field` to `foo_field`. It is a conflict in logic. It must be solved during database designing stage.